Couple has a romance, one of them jumps off a building
I'm trying to find the name of a movie I saw someone cut and edit as a music clip online. I can't find the video so I'm looking for the original film as a result.
The film was set in blue/grey tones, kinda dimly lit and the couple is having a romance. At a certain point, one of them (can't remember which one actually) goes to the roof on top of the big building, takes some balance and jumps off. Nearly at the same time, the significant other is reaching the rooftop and sees him/her jumping off.
I remember the girl looking somewhat like Milla Jovovich, but I could be completely off.
Edit: I'd say the movie was probably made in the 90's to early 2000's.

@Catija Nope, but thank you.

Sounds like that scene in Inception where Mal dies.

@Dredd I realize that it really does, but that's not it. Thank you!

so the girl jumps or the guy jumps?

Is this it? A music clip edited from The Million Dollar Hotel from 2000 with a blue-tinted scene of the young man jumping off a roof and the startled Milla Jovovich (after the 5 minute mark) who goes up there but can't stop it in time:




thank you so much for finding the movie that I tried to describe. I wasn't that far. :) Unfortunately, the music clip I was trying to find was “La Ritournelle” by Sebastien Tellier featuring this same clip but it appears to have been taken down since. Cheers for such a quick reply.
